# How many Activity Diagrams for Multiple Scenarios ? (UML 2.0)

Tags: android, android-activity, uml, diagram

A machine produces two types of products, Product A and Product B, using its mechanical components in a different way.

Do I have to create an Activity Diagram for each production process or can I create an Activity Diagram for both?

Comment: One Activity is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it both ways depending on your needs and your purpose... There is no general answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

If there are preconditions/influencing factors under which the machine is producing products A, B and you intend to include the preconditions in the diagram, you can go with a single diagram.

Some influencing factors could be the demand for products,availability of raw materials etc.